# Unexpected EOF while looking for a matching `''

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following (redacted) script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

if ps -lf | grep cata |  perl -ane '($h,$m,$s) = split /:/,$F +[13]; kill 9, $F[3] if ($h > 1); then
   ...    
else
   ...
fi
set +x
```

When running this script I'm getting this error:

```
/bin/kill.sh: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/kill.sh: line 20: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What is wrong?

Comment: try: `... perl -ane '($h,$m,$s) = split /:/,$F +[13]; kill 9, $F[3] if ($h > 1)'; ...`. I added an "'" before the ";".

Comment: BY the way, `$F+[13]` is really not what you want. Presumably, you meant `$F[13]`.

Comment: I think it's kind of ridiculous that only one person has [nearly] simplified their answer and/or comment to "you're missing a terminating single-quote (`'`), which is obviously causing the error in question."

Comment: @rubynorails that is just one of many, many errors. The Perl script is also completely wrong. Fixing the closing quote will not correct the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't closed the `perl` command. It needs to be `perl 'foo'` and you have `perl 'foo` instead. Just change your script to:

```
if ps -lf | grep cata |  
    perl -ane '($h,$m,$s) = split /:/,$F +[13]; kill 9, $F[3] if ($h > 1)'; then
```

That will take care of the syntax error. However, your script will still not work as you expect. First of all, when you run `ps | grep foo`, you will always get at least one result: the grep process itself:

```
$  ps -lf | grep cata
0 S terdon    6400  4889  0  80   0 -  3183 -      19:03 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color cata
```

Second, you aren't telling your `perl` script to exit with a different status depending on whether it matched. Therefore, your `if` condition will always be true since the perl script will always run, irrespective of whether it is doing anything useful.

---

More to the point, you are reinventing the wheel. If I understand correctly, you want to kill the `cata` process if it has been running for more than an hour. At least I *think* that's what you expect your Perl script to do (it doesn't, but never mind). If so, all you need is:

```
kill -9 $(ps -o pid=,etimes= -p $(pgrep cata) | awk '$2>3600{print $1}')
```

That might need some explaining. The `ps` command can be told to list only specific PIDs with the `-p` option and to print only specific fields of output with the `-o`. Here, I am telling it to print the PID and the elapsed time in seconds. The `pgrep` command prints any PIDs mathing the pattern given. So, `ps -p $(pgrep cata)` will run `ps` on any `PID` whose process matches `cata`.

Since the `-o` flag is telling `ps` to only print the PID and the elapsed time, the `awk` will check whether the elapsed time (the second field, `$2`) is greater than an hour (3600 seconds) and, if so, it will print the first field, the PID. So, the result of the `ps ... | awk` will be the list of PID of `cata` processes that have been running for more than an hour. This list is then given to the `kill -9` command.

Comment: That's also reinventing the `pkill` wheel...

Comment: @WouterVerhelst how do you get `pkill` to only kill processes that have been running for more than an hour?

Comment: this results in usage error from kill if there are no `cata` processes that have been running for more than an hour.  use `| xargs -r kill -9` instead.  also OP should supply full name of process so it can be found with `pc -C`.

Comment: that's a pretty neat trick. dont forget etimes does leading colon divided components for day old processes

Answer (score 3):

Add an `'` before `;` you have actually forgotten it:

```
if ps -lf | grep cata | perl -ane '($h,$m,$s) = split /:/,$F +[13]; kill 9, $F[3] if ($h > 1)'; then
```

Comment: I didn't want @terdon 2 modify my answer but give me a suggestion comment!

Comment: Huh? I just fixed the formatting and removed the [excessive exclamation marks](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-law-of-exclamation). Editing answers is very much [a part of](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/editing) how this site works.

Comment: @terdon From a meme???

Comment: The meme was an attempt at humor. The main point is that this site tries, even succeeds sometimes, to have clear, grammatically and syntactically correct questions and answers. So, excessive punctuation and textspeak should be avoided. I think we're having trouble communicating. It might be easier to have a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) about it. Αν είναι θέμα γλώσας, τα λέμε και στα ελληνικά. Κάποια παρεξήγηση παίζει.

Comment: @terdon hahahahahaha εντάξει έβαλα άνω-κάτω τελεία. If it's a matter of language, I put a colon instead of an !.